# How to implement service using xfire in grails to store data in database?

Tags: grails, xfire

Hi i am using xfire plugin in grails app,Belov is service written,

```
class HelloWorldService {

static expose=['xfire']
void addBook(String pName,String pAuthor) {
    def b=new Book()
    b.name=pName
    b.author=pAuthor
    println b.name
    println b.author
    if(!b.save())
    {
        b.errors.each { println it }
    }
    else
    {
        println "saved"
    }

}
}
```

when client requests this addBook method with parameters, getting error as,

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   patienthealthhistory.Book.save() is applicable for argument types: ()
>   values: []

why is it so?

PLz can anybody help me to solve this issue..Waiting for answer..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error is occurring on this line

```
if(!b.save())
```

The only reason I can think of why the `save()` method would be missing is that `Book` is not a domain class

Comment: :Book is a domain class..when i call same service method from controller action save works but client requests service directly as webservice then its not!!

Comment: When i use it as webservice with xfire then its not working.i think i am missing something with using xfire for web service.